# How to always show Prev/Next links, inside pagination pattern?

Tags: pagination, full-site-editing

WordPress full site editing. How to always display the “prev page” & “next page”, in the pagination? Currently, the prev-page/next-page, hides when there's no prev/next posts in the query loop.

Is it possible, add some conditions/modifiers to the template page, that will make these two links, to always show?

```
<!-- wp:query-pagination -->
   <!-- wp:query-pagination-previous /-->
   <!-- wp:query-pagination-numbers /-->
   <!-- wp:query-pagination-next /-->
<!-- /wp:query-pagination -->
```